# Use jBPM 5.4 with a simple Java EE application

Tags: hibernate, jbpm, business-process-management

i'm currently working in jBPM 5.4 with jBOSS 7.1

i have changed my backend db to MS-SQL using the link https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpJBPM54FinalInstallerToUseMSSQLServer2008UsingJTDS

Followed the steps provided by https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/09/21/jbpm5-web-example

I'm using the following transaction manager,

Unfortunately when i initiate a process from the servlet, i get the following stacktrace,

```
58:12,868 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) @@@@@@@@ Start Process + Begin + JBPMAPIUTIL
15:58:12,874 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.processserver.JbpmAPIUtil] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Value of processDefId : com.sample.bpmn.hello
15:58:12,878 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.processserver.JbpmAPIUtil] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Value of processName : sample.bpmn
15:58:12,882 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ initiate process


15:58:12,886 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Creating Session


15:58:12,890 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.processserver.JbpmAPIUtil] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Value of processNames : [sample.bpmn]
15:58:12,895 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.processserver.JbpmAPIUtil] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Value of processNames : [sample.bpmn]
15:58:12,899 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) ------------ within create session ------------


15:58:12,959 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.handler.CustomExceptionHandler] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) ------------------------------------ERROR-------------------------------------
15:58:12,966 ERROR [main.java.com.sample.handler.CustomExceptionHandler] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) STACK TRACE: org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
15:58:12,972 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.handler.CustomExceptionHandler] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) ------------------------------------ERROR-------------------------------------
15:58:12,978 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.persistence.jpa] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory


15:58:12,987 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)


15:58:12,993 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)


15:58:12,999 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)


15:58:13,006 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)


15:58:13,011 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)


15:58:13,020 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at main.java.com.sample.processserver.JbpmAPIUtil.createSession(JbpmAPIUtil.java:521)


15:58:13,025 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at main.java.com.sample.processserver.JbpmAPIUtil.initiateProcess(JbpmAPIUtil.java:473)


15:58:13,036 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at main.java.com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet.processRequest(TaskProcessServlet.java:96)


15:58:13,046 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at main.java.com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet.doGet(TaskProcessServlet.java:267)


15:58:13,053 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)


15:58:13,057 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)


15:58:13,061 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)


15:58:13,068 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)


15:58:13,074 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)


15:58:13,079 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)


15:58:13,084 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)


15:58:13,089 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)


15:58:13,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)


15:58:13,100 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)


15:58:13,107 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)


15:58:13,113 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)


15:58:13,120 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)


15:58:13,125 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)


15:58:13,130 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)


15:58:13,135 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


15:58:13,144 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS]


15:58:13,149 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:92)


15:58:13,154 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:63)


15:58:13,159 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)


15:58:13,166 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)


15:58:13,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)


15:58:13,178 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)


15:58:13,185 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234)


15:58:13,192 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91)


15:58:13,199 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)


15:58:13,205 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)


15:58:13,211 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)


15:58:13,218 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)


15:58:13,222 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)


15:58:13,229 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)


15:58:13,234 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)


15:58:13,239 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)


15:58:13,245 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)


15:58:13,250 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           ... 24 more


15:58:13,253 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Caused by: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException


15:58:13,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext.getNameParser(BitronixContext.java:140)


15:58:13,262 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)


15:58:13,267 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)


15:58:13,273 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)           ... 40 more


15:58:13,275 INFO  [main.java.com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) @@@@@@@@ Start Process + Initiate + Completed
15:58:13,281 WARN  [bitronix.tm.twopc.Preparer] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) executing transaction with 0 enlisted resource
15:58:13,287 WARN  [bitronix.tm.utils.ManagementRegistrar] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) cannot unregister object with name bitronix.tm:type=Transaction,Gtrid=31302E3233302E31342E3130360000013C71401D5400000002: bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixRuntimeException: cannot callunregisterMBean
          at bitronix.tm.utils.ManagementRegistrar.mbeanServerCall(ManagementRegistrar.java:95) [btm-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
          at bitronix.tm.utils.ManagementRegistrar.unregister(ManagementRegistrar.java:74) [btm-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
          at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.fireAfterCompletionEvent(BitronixTransaction.java:388) [btm-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
          at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:188) [btm-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
          at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.commit(BitronixTransactionManager.java:96) [btm-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
          at main.java.com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet.processRequest(TaskProcessServlet.java:98) [classes:]
          at main.java.com.sample.processserver.TaskProcessServlet.doGet(TaskProcessServlet.java:267) [classes:]
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
          at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class bitronix.tm.utils.ManagementRegistrar can not access a member of class org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl with modifiers "public"
          at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
          at bitronix.tm.utils.ManagementRegistrar.mbeanServerCall(ManagementRegistrar.java:93) [btm-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
          ... 22 more
```

when i perform the same action again, i get such an exception **Bitronix Transaction Manager - cannot open disk journal**

Could any provide me guidance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error is related with the JNDI resource. If you are running in JBoss you shouldn't be using bitronix, you need to use the JBoss Transaction services inside the AS. For that you will need to modify your persistence.xml file and change this property:

To use the jboss one. 
Then you need to make sure that you have correctly configured the following data source inside jboss: java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS

Cheers

Comment: this the property i'm using in persistence.xml 
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
I'm actually a newbie to jBPM or hibernate kind of stuff. 

i'm sure abt the value to be placed in java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS 

Anyhow if the jbpm console is working fine, wont the JNDI name be configure properly ?